# button not showing on my jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to add the View, Update, and Delete button to my jquery server side Datatable. as show on the image below only the delete button is showing

[image]
    Javascript

```
<script>
var enabletemplateListVM;
    $(function () {
        enabletemplateListVM = {
            dt: null,
            init: function () {
                dt = $('#templatemessage-data-table').DataTable({
                    "dom": '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/MessageTemplate/LoadData",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
```

I want the button below to display in the same column

```
                    "columns": [                       
                       {

                            "targets": [0], "data": "TemplateId", "render": function (data, type, full)
                            {
                                return '@Html.ActionLink("View", "View", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);

                            },
                            "targets": [0], "data": "TemplateId", "render": function (data, type, full)
                            {
                                return '@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);
                            },
                             "targets": [0], "data": "TemplateId", "render": function (data, type, full)
                             {
                                 return '@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);
                             }
                        },
                        { "title": "Template Id", "data": "TemplateId", "name": "TemplateId", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "title": "Team Name", "data": "TeamName", "name": "TeamName", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "title": "Template Name", "data": "TemplateName", "name": "TemplateName", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "title": "Description", "data": "Description", "name": "Description", "autoWidth": true },

                    ],
                    "lengthMenu": [[100, 50, 80], [100, 50, 80]],
                });
           }
        }
        // initialize the datatables 
        enabletemplateListVM.init();
    });
  </script
```

Comment: its because after each return of buttons, it replace it, like first return view, 2nd return replace view with update and 3rd update with delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return all buttons together as they all are for same column, 
your code is replace buttons to new, and end up with only last button

```
          "columns": [                       
                   {

                        "targets": [0], 
                       "data": "TemplateId", 
                        "render": function (data, type, full)
                        {
                            var a = '@Html.ActionLink("View", "View", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);
                          var b = '@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);
                           var c =  '@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);
                          return a+b+c;
                        },


                    },
                    { "title": "Template Id", "data": "TemplateId", "name": "TemplateId", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "title": "Team Name", "data": "TeamName", "name": "TeamName", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "title": "Template Name", "data": "TemplateName", "name": "TemplateName", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "title": "Description", "data": "Description", "name": "Description", "autoWidth": true },

                ],
```

Comment: Thanks Sunny for your help

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the **1st Column definition**

```
{

    "targets": [0], "data": "TemplateId", "render": function (data, type, full)
    {
        return '@Html.ActionLink("View", "View", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);

    },
    "targets": [0], "data": "TemplateId", "render": function (data, type, full)
    {
        return '@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);
    },
     "targets": [0], "data": "TemplateId", "render": function (data, type, full)
     {
         return '@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);
     }
},
```

It will always pick last one

To resolve this you need only `1 render function` like this

```
"targets": [0], "data": "TemplateId", "render": function (data, type, full)
{

    // define view button
    var view = '@Html.ActionLink("View", "View", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);

    // define update button
    var update = '@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);

    // define delete Button
    var delete =  '@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = "TemplateId" })'.replace("TemplateId", data);


    return view+update+delete;  // return all three button

},
```